# How to provide mathematical proof of the security of a stream cipher against known attacks?

Tags: stream-cipher

Suppose a person has invented a stream cipher and he/she wants to get it published.

I have a few questions:

1. In addition to providing detailed description of the algorithm, how would he/she give mathematical proof of its security against known attacks? Are there any things that are specifically expected to be described or proven in a paper that introduces a new cipher?
2. Are some kinds of attacks more important than others, or are they all equally important?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to publish a cipher (concept)?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33274/how-to-publish-a-cipher-concept)

Comment: The third point is pretty much completely off topic. The first is answered in the above link and e.g. [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15908/how-do-you-test-the-security-of-your-cipher). The second seems on topic, non-dupe, somewhat broad but acceptable. Could you ask these (2. and 1. if you think it is not a duplicate) separately?

Comment: @Raoul722 Only for point 1. Point 2 is still on topic.