# Disadvantages of AES-CTR?

Tags: aes, ctr

On paper, it sounds *very* good to me:

- secure
- fast (in my tests it's somewhat slower than ECB (but without most of the weaknesses, more on that below) but faster than every other alternative I tested, which were `ECB, CTR, CBC, OFB, CFB` written in order of performance ([link to benchmark code](https://paste.debian.net/1167253/)) )
- simple to understand
- does not require padding (which I guess significantly reduces the chance of implementing padding in an insecure manner)
- support parallelization (for both encryption and decryption)
- support random access

.. the only disadvantage I can think of, is that because it does not require padding, implementations in practice will probably reveal *the exact message length*, as compared to revealing circa-message-lengths (e.g. padded schemes may reveal something like `the message is within 15 bytes of this length`, while non-padded schemes may reveal `the message is *exactly* this long`), and if that's a concern, it's not like it can't be mitigated by just adding padding anyway.

I guess I'm missing something, so...

**What are the disadvantages?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Disadvantages:**

- **Message length:** In Cryptography, usually, the message length is not considered secret. There are approaches that you can add random values to the end or beginning or both if this is really an information leak for you. The random approach depends on your actual data case. It is also possible that a pre-determined fixed size can be used as the e-mail can be limited to 512 characters. In the end, at least the upper bound is revealed in all of the cases.
- **The (IV, key) pair reuse** is a real problem that can eliminate confidentiality with the crib-dragging technique. This doesn't reveal the encryption key.
- **Lack of authentication** Like all unauthenticated encryption modes, the bare CTR mode lacks integrity and authentication. A single bit of flipping can have catastrophic results due to [the malleability of the CTR mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/33846/18298).

  The [AES-GCM](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/84359/18298) mode that uses the CTR mode of operation provides you all-in-once, however, it has the same  (IV, key) pair reuse problem. There is a Synthetic Initialization Vector (SIV) mode as nonce-misuse resistance ( [paper](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75305/18298), [rfc8452](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75305/18298) ) that eliminates this. SIV mode can still leak that the same message is sent under the same key, so an observer can distinguish this.
- **Long message distinguisher:**  The CTR mode is designed with a Pseudo-Random-Function (PRF). When using AES in CTR mode, we use it with Pseudo Random Permutation (PRP); $$E_k\colon \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^n.$$ Whit PRP as long as the message blocks are not repeated the sequence $E_k(0), E_k(1), \dots, E_k(\ell - 1)$ with $\ell < 2^n$ is not repeated. If the message with length $\ell$-block has no repeated block this is no problem. If we approach the message as uniform random block then we expect a collision $\ell \approx \sqrt{2^n} = 2^{n/2}$ by the birthday paradox/attack.

  When used with AES-128 for long messages check for the repeat. The repeat enables the attacker to distinguish this from uniform random with [non-negligible probability](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75305/18298).

  In short, a duplicate ciphertext in any position leaks that the messages are different.
- **Message size per key:** although NIST say 64 nonce and 64 bit counter, one should stop using a key well before $2^{64}$ block. This is due to [using a PRP (AES) instead of PRF in CTR mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75543/18298).

---

**Other advantages:**

1. **No need for the decryption:** CTR mode doesn't require decryption of the block cipher, it always uses them for encryption. This is very helpful in constraint environments. Simplifies the software and hardware code, too.
2. **No need PRP:** Doesn't need a block cipher (PRP) at all. A [hash function](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1656/18298) can be used like in the ChaCha series.
3. **Prepocessing:** the keystream generated by the CTR mode can be prepared before. This can help to use buffers.
4. CTR mode has **CPA security**.

---

**A little history of CTR**

CTR mode was introduced by Whitfield Diffie and Martin Hellman in 1979

- [Privacy and Authentication: An Introduction to Cryptography](https://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Erogaway/papers/siv.pdf) as an invited paper on Proceedings of the IEEE, 67 (1979), pp. 397–427.
- [A concrete Security of Treatment of Symmetric Encryption, Bellare et. al, 97](https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Erogaway/papers/sym-enc.pdf) provides the security bounds.
- See also; [Comments to NIST concerning AES Modes of Operations: CTR-Mode Encryption](https://web.archive.org/web/20150226072817/http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/ctr/ctr-spec.pdf), by Lipmaa et al. for other details of advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: to be fair, if you re-use IV's, i think you have a problem no matter what mode you use ^^

Comment: Not exactly the same problem in all modes, Consider the CBC mode, It encrypts the messages with chaining.

Comment: It allows for "online" encryption as well, missing in the OP's question and this answer. As for message length: you can add a random sized padding, but that doesn't fully hide all information about the size. Similarly, using AES in SIV mode doesn't hide nonce reuse for identical messages (i.e. it will protect most of the information about the message, but it still may leak *some* information about the plaintext: messages that are identical could be distinguished from other messages).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I think I'm not familiar with the online encryption. Yes, the random padding or up to a fixed size ( for example for e-mails up to 512-char). In the end there is information about the upper size. Yes SIV mode reveals that. I need to edit that, the links messed today, again. Thanks.

Comment: Online encryption / decryption is just the ability of directly encrypting any bit / byte or block of bits / bytes offered. E.g. with CBC you'd have to buffer some bytes until you have a full block. This is useful e.g. when decrypting from a stream.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Isn't it same as the random access property listed in the OPs question?

Comment: It's certainly related, in case you want a random byte decrypted then you can do that directly without decrypting a whole block. But I guess you can have block sized random access e.g. when using ECB. I'm not sure how well these kind of properties are defined.

Comment: @hanshenrik: When many encryption modes, reuse of an initialization vector may give an attacker information about which blocks match each other, but would not compromise anything else.  By contrast, when using CTR mode, reuse of an initialization vector is completely disastrous.

Comment: @hanshenrik: When using CFB, for example, reuse of an IV on two files that start with the same prefix would allow an attacker to determine that both files start with the same prefix, but would reveal essentially nothing about the files past the block containing the first difference.  By contrast, when using CTR, if two files sent with the same IV match except for the insertion of a byte near the beginning, someone who can guess what that byte is (out of only 256 possibilities!) would be able to decrypt *everything* past the insertion point without having to know or care about the key!

Comment: While it is implicitly included in "lack of authentication", I'd specifically call out the **malleability** of CTR mode as a deal breaker these days. Unlike with other malleable modes, such as CBC, very precise changes can be made to the plaintext the receiver gets. "Catastrophic results" indeed.

Comment: @user7761803 yes, malleable is the other term. Even in the CBC mode, the bit flipping attack can be executed precisely. If you play with the IV's bit that will only affect single bit. [This can be seen in the image of this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/66086/18298). I've considered making a bullet about that but decided to keep it in the lack of authentication as a broader bullet.

Comment: @user7761803 the malleability/bit-flipping problem is only a problem when lacking a MAC though, right?

Comment: @hanshenrik for the CTR mode, yes the authentication ( as long as doesn't allow forgeries) can prevent the malleability by checking the tag. Keep in mind that, in modern cryptography, we talk about the advantage of the adversary and we want to keep it negligible. negligible != 0 but an infinitesimal number...

Comment: @hanshenrik Only if you don't forget to include the IV in the MAC calculations. Assuming that the IV is malleable of course.

Answer (score 2):

Schneier and Ferguson initially recommended CTR mode, but switched to recommending CBC mode due to potential difficulties in ensuring that the counter was never re-used with a key.

Comment: Could you add the link of the claim?

Comment: @kelalaka "Cryptography Engineering" p.71 (Section 4.7 in Chapter 4, "Block Cipher Modes") ©2010 Wily Publishing

Comment: And, it turned out that the Padding oracles was the key attack for the CBC mode. If you limit the counter to 32 bits as in the GCM, you will have more options to secure the CTR. IV = Random+ counter. If anything happens change the key and use AES-256. +1 for the information.

Comment: CBC has its own [issues with IV misuse](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1312/using-a-non-random-iv-with-modes-other-than-cbc), however. If you're worried about IV/nonce reuse, the real solution is to use an MRAE mode such as [SIV](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5297).

Answer (score 2):

While your question seems to be focusing on the CTR side of things, its worth an answer to discuss the AES side of things as well.
There are *at least* two situations where other block ciphers may be more appropriate.

---

**Secure Computation**:

There are two main "difficulties" of AES with respect to secure computation (meaning multi-party computation and NIZKs mainly, but also likely fully-homomorphic encryption).

1. AES is computed over a field of characteristic 2. If an MPC/FHE system uses characteristic $p$ arithmetic, the having a cipher in characteristic 2 requires conversions between different representations (say, of an element in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, or the base-2 decomposition of such an element) which are more costly than in standard computation.
2. Generically, multiplications are *much* more costly (relatively) than additions in the context of secure computation. This means that one can have a different "cost model" to build ciphers for, where one is more interested in reducing the number of multiplications in the cipher generically.

A cipher to look at for this topic is [MiMC](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/492.pdf) (although there was recently a [partial attack](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/182) against this cipher in a "$\mathbb{F}_{2^k}$ version" of it.
It also has "$\mathbb{F}_p$" versions, which are not hit by the attack).

---

**Embedded Systems**:

On standard machines, the hardware implementation of AES (via the AES-NI instruction) gives something like a ~40x speedup over optimized software implementations of AES.
This makes it difficult to be competitive with AES when comparing AES-NI to software implementations of other ciphers.
But when you *don't* have AES-NI, other ciphers can be more competitive.
[This post by Matthew Green](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2012/10/09/so-you-want-to-use-alternative-cipher/) discusses using alternative to AES (his recommendation when writing this ~8 years ago was *not* do this, for the record) discusses certain ciphers like Salsa20 offering a 2x - 3x speedup over AES in software.
Note that Salsa20 is technically a stream cipher compared to AES being a block cipher, but this is just to motivate being able to "beat" AES on speed when you *don't* have access to AES-NI.

A better source for faster ciphers in constrained computing environments is the ongoing [NIST Lightweight Cryptography Standardization](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Lightweight-Cryptography).
I have not been following this closely, but there is currently much research interest in finding a *new* cipher to standardize for (essentially) use in embedded systems.
They are currently planning to post their round 3 finalists this upcoming December, so it would not surprise me if within the next few years there was a "new cipher" which replaces the use of AES in embedded systems.

Answer (score 1):

CTR is indeed a very nice block cipher mode of operation.  Its main drawbacks are that:

1. it does not protect message integrity (and in fact allows an attacker to easily flip arbitrary bits in an encrypted message without having to decrypt it), and
2. it may leak plaintext if a counter block is ever reused; in particular, CTR mode encryption requires a unique nonce input that absolutely must not be reused for two different messages encrypted with the same key.

Fortunately, both of these problems may be solved by using CTR mode as a component in a higher-level construction:

- The first problem can be solved by using an [authenticated encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) mode, many of which (such as [EAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode) and [GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode)) are based on a combination of CTR mode with a [message authentication code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code).
- The second problem can be solved by using a "nonce misuse resistant" encryption mode that derives the initial counter value based on (among other things) the plaintext message being encrypted.  Such modes include [SIV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5297) and [GCM-SIV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES-GCM-SIV), both of which are also based on CTR mode and also provide message authentication as described above.

Of course, the addition of message authentication requires some extra processing that makes these modes slower than raw CTR (although a good implementation of GCM can still be *very* fast).  In particular, to obtain the full security these modes guarantee, the receiver must authenticate the entire message before passing on any of the decrypted plaintext.  For the misuse resistant modes, the same also applies when encrypting, since the entire message must be processed to derive the initial counter value before it can be encrypted.

Still that's generally a small price to pay for increased security.  If you can use a nonce misuse resistant mode like SIV or GCM-SIV, I'd highly recommend you do so.  If not, at least use a nonce-based AE mode like GCM.