# Is there any real attack deployed on the CTR mode over history?

Tags: aes, des, ctr

The CTR mode, with its [CPA security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-plaintext_attack), is one of the [malleable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malleability_(cryptography)) [block cipher mode of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation). An attacker can simply modify the bits of the ciphertext stream in their advance. This is due to the lack of integrity and that can be easily prevented with an [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC). With Encrypt-then-MAC $$(c,IV) = \operatorname{AES-CTR}(IV,message)$$ and $$tag = \operatorname{HMAC-SHA256}(key,IV\mathbin\|c)$$

We have seen lots of real examples on the CBC mode due to the [padding oracle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_oracle_attack) over the years. Padding oracle attack, however, is not applicable to CTR mode since it doesn't require any padding at all.

- Is there any real attack deployed on the CTR mode over history?<sup>*</sup>

<sub><sup>*</sup>Note: This question come into my mind while answering this question; [Disadvantages of AES-CTR?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/85572/18298)</sub>

Comment: attacks on the mode would probably be on subset of implementations that lack authentication, I would hope that any of those would be considered implementation mistakes

Comment: @RichieFrame yes indeed, it would be a lack of authentication or ignoring the incorrect tag due to the bad/illiterate coding.

Comment: CTR nonce reuse is a thing that happens. As is choosing the nonce to be incrementing counter in a way that causes partial keystream reuse between messages.

Comment: @JackLloyd Yes, and it is known from the beginning. What we are looking for here is a real attack case like done padding oracle attacks in TSL over the year.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "real attack case"? I have found both of these bugs in commercial cryptographic software during reviews. If you are looking for a public example I believe Tarsnap had a repeated CTR nonce bug.

Comment: @JackLloyd A real attack may contain CVE and/or an article, not disclosed ones. Tarnap any paper about it? I looked but couldn't find. Thanks. You can still write an answer, and I will upvote.